# Getting error after adding arguments in constructor

Tags: magento2, model, exception

I have added model in my constructor

```
public function __construct(
    Context $context,
    PageFactory $resultPageFactory,
    \Vendor\Module\Model\Productsgrid $model
)
{
    $this->model = $model;
    $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
    return parent::__construct($context);
}
```

After adding model I am getting this error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to
>   function...

When I am removing `Productsgrid` model it's working fine, am I doing something wrong?

Comment: have you run upgrade command one time ?

Comment: Whenever you change something in constructor, you need to remove generated folder of magento. You can use 'rm -rf generated/*' to overcome this whenever you change constructor arguments.

Comment: Please remove generated/ and php bin/magento cache:clean then it will work, no need of upgrade or deploying stuffs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens with me before. You need to run upgrade dicompile and full deployment script

```
php -dmemory_limit=1G bin/magento setup:upgrade
php -dmemory_limit=1G bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer --skip-compilation
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy --theme Magento/backend -f
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy --theme Naheed/NaheedTheme -f
php bin/magento cache:clean
```

This will resolve your issue

Comment: @divyasekar I will try